# Can we pay more attention when voting to close questions?

Tags: discussion, closing, reviewing

Recently we've had a few questions closed that perhaps shouldn't have been, or should have been closed with a different reason. I don't want to dig up the obvious candidate here, that has it's own question and discussion. This question is prompted by the following closure:

[Skyrim; Finn's Lute; Converting xbox 360 save to PC to resolve - Reopen Queue](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/37122)

[Finn's Lute bug; Converting Xbox 360 save to PC to resolve](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/117537/skyrim-finns-lute-converting-xbox-360-save-to-pc-to-resolve)

This was closed as a duplicate to the following two questions;

- [How to edit save game file?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79181/how-to-edit-save-game-file)
- [Convert save game to a different platform](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57205/convert-save-game-to-a-different-platform)

The former I can relate with, the answer clearly states the process of transferring a Xbox save to PC, making edits, and then transferring it back. The second question, however, is a Mass Effect question.

This should go without saying and I'm not going to point fingers at the people who voted in this instance, but in general - please, can we pay more attention when voting to close questions? If you don't want to pay attention, then please refrain from working through the review queues.

Comment: Not to mention that the Mass Effect Q is answered with nothing but further on-site links.

Comment: Oh.  The question for Mass Effect only references it in the tag, and the answers are links to other answers.  Missed that.  That one should be duped to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53213/can-i-transfer-mass-effect-saved-game-files-from-my-pc-to-my-xbox360, as it doesn't do anything but link to that and another question duped to that same one.